# How do I copy the stock launcher's layout of widgets, icons, and folders from the old Nexus 6 to the new Pixel?

Tags: updates, nexus-6, google-pixel

I received my new Pixel today (Yay!) and I went through the installation.  During which I was asked to migrate my old phone info using the Google app.  (My old phone is the Nexus 6 not the 6P).  It happily downloaded and installed all my apps and settings (at least I hope all of my settings since I see my background has copied).

Now, when reinstalling my OS on my Nexus 6 from time to time (such as the dev preview), I always was able to restore my home screen layout along with all other settings.

Is this not possible when upgrading between physical phones?  I figured that Android would be able to migrate this data since it's the same OS version using stock Google launcher with the same 5x5 icon layout.  However I can't seem to find any information about it.

It will take me a very long time to migrate all my stuff manually since I have  many, many folders so any help would be appreciated.  (I'm all for getting under the hood too.)

Comment: Were you using a custom launcher or the stock Google Launcher on the N6?  Widgets are always problematic, even using something like Nova Launcher and restoring a backup isn't always 100%, but it gets you mostly there.

Comment: I am using the stock Launcher.  I will edit question to reflect this.